# How to use localstorage to remember appended items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

Here's an **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/aqZ6P/16/)** in which images and hidden inputs get added to the div container `#area` on click. I want to use localstorage to remember the appended items on page load, but it isn't working with this line

```
localStorage.setItem("imagecookie",$('#area').find('div:empty:first').append(img).append(input));

...
localStorage.getItem("imagecookie");
```

Could anyone show me how to get it to work?

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
<img data-term="A" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5d/Crystal_Clear_action_run.png/40px-Crystal_Clear_action_run.png"/>
<input data-term="A" class="compare" type="checkbox"/>
</div>

<div class="box">
<img data-term="B" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/99/Question_book-new.svg/50px-Question_book-new.svg.png"/>
<input data-term="B" class="compare" type="checkbox"/>
</div>

<div class="box">
<img data-term="C" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/4a/Commons-logo.svg/30px-Commons-logo.svg.png"/>
<input data-term="C" class="compare" type="checkbox"/>
</div>

<div id="area"><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
```

Code:

```
$('.compare').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
    var img = $('<img>'),
    findimg = $(this).closest('.box').find('img'),
    data_term = findimg.data('term');
    img.attr('src', findimg.attr('src'));
    img.attr('data-term',data_term);
    var input = '<input type="hidden" name="imagecompare" value="'+data_term+'">';
        localStorage.setItem("imagecookie",$('#area').find('div:empty:first').append(img).append(input));
    }
    else{
    var term = $(this).data('term'),
        findboximage = $('#area > div > img[data-term='+term+']')
        findboximage.parent('div').empty();
    }
});

$(document).on('click','#area > div',function(){
  $(this).empty();
  localStorage.clear();
});

localStorage.getItem("imagecookie");
```

Comment: localstorage stores the data as string... so when you pass a jQuery object to local storage it gets stored as `[object Object]`

Comment: You can store it by `$('#area').find('div:empty:first').html()`

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Crm2J/2/

Comment: @Arun P Johny. Thank you very much. Is local-storage possible to work across pages? Suppose `#area` is always present at the top of the site, and when I page through different pages, can #area still remember the appended items?

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aqZ6P/22/)** : Store the contents; Retrieve back on page reload.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aqZ6P/23/)** : Just store the contents - Check the console to verify.

Storing HTML content  would be a better option.

```
$('#area').find('div:empty:first').append(img).append(input)
localStorage.setItem("imagecookie",$('#area').html());
```